# How to use org.apache.struts.config.SecureActionConfig in struts2

Tags: struts2, migration, struts-1

We are migrating project from Struts1 to Struts2 but unable to find  org.apache.struts.config.SecureActionConfig class in struts2 jar file, however it is working fine in struts1 project.
Can anyone help how to use org.apache.struts.config.SecureActionConfig class in struts2 project?